# Batch: How to prevent looping code when holding enter

Tags: loops, batch-file, enter

So iv'e made a little something here where there will be a list of numbers like 1-10 and whichever one you type (so far only 1) will show you information (so if i type and enter 1, it will go key1=key).

However, if I type 1 and click enter, it shows me that the Key1 = key which i intended but then if I hold down Enter key, it will keep looping the Key1=Key script and the homepage one, can this be stopped?

```
@echo off
:T
cls

echo Home Page
echo [1] NameA
echo.
echo [e] Exit

set /p word=
if "%word%"=="1" goto aaa
if "%word%"=="e" goto eee
goto T

:aaa
cls
echo Key1 = Key
pause
goto T

:eee
exit
```

Comment: You're asking it to do exactly the behaviour you've described. How about you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54386686/edit) to include what you'd like to happen, not just what you wouldn't.

Comment: To stop such a behavior, stop to hold down Enter key... **`;)`** ... or insert `set "word="` command before the `set /p word=` one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:T
cls

echo Home Page
echo [1] NameA
echo.
echo [e] Exit

rem Undefine variable word before input.
set "word="

set /p "word="

rem No input = word is not set a new value, thus not defined.
if not defined word goto eee

if "%word%"=="1" goto aaa
if "%word%"=="e" goto eee
goto T

:aaa
cls
echo Key1 = Key
pause
goto T

:eee
exit
```

If you only press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the `set /p` prompt, variable `word` is not set (a new value).
If `word` is undefined before the `set /p` input, then it will be undefined after,
if you only press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`setlocal` added to keep variables set local to the current script
execution.

Answer (score 1):

`set /p` keeps the last value, if you just press enter. You should set the variable to empty (or a default value, if you prefer):

```
@echo off
:loop
REM set "word="  ; for "empty"
set "word=string"
set /p "word=Enter your choice (or just ENTER for '%word%': "
echo you choosed %word%
goto :loop
```

May I bring your attention to the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command, which may (or may not) be a better choice.